Is there any way to have a Unique, Read Only Collection?
I have a big enumeration like this:
public enum RetirementTypes
{
   k401 = 1,
   b403 = 2,
   b457 = 3,
   SimpleIRA = 4,
   Simple401k = 5,
   TIRA = 6,
   RIRA = 7,
   RothIRA = 8,
   Solo401k = 9,
   SEPIRA = 10,
   FA = 11,
   VA = 12,
   ESOP = 14,
   PERA = 15,
   VL = 16,
   SpousalIRA = 17,
   BIRA = 19,
   OtherRetirement = 22,
   TSP = 23,
   OtherIra = 24,
   BRoth = 33
   ...
}//RetirementTypes

and I want to define in some of my components some subsets of these Types. Ideally my list should be a constant/read only and contain Unique items and would be nice if I would be aware of Unique problem at the compile time (I doubt there is any solution for this).
So far I use IReadOnlyCollection. For example this subset is to identify some IRAs types :
IReadOnlyCollection<RetirementTypes> RETIREMENT_IRA_TYPES = [RetirementTypes.SEPIRA, 
RetirementTypes.BIRA, RetirementTypes.RothIRA, RetirementTypes.OtherIra,RetirementTypes.RIRA, RetirementTypes.SpousalIRA, RetirementTypes.OtherIra, RetirementTypes.RothIRA ...]

The future use of it is a filter in various queries like:
iw.WbRetirements.Where(x => x.Owner == (int)OwnerType.Self && RETIREMENT_IRA_TYPES.Contains((RetirementTypes)x.RetirementPlanType)).Sum(b => b.Balance);


Sounds like an IReadOnlySet<T> / FrozenSet<T> / ImmutableHashSet<T>? Those won't give you a compile-time error about non-unique members, but they'll ignore duplicate members at runtime, and the Contains test will be O(1) rather than O(n) (the ImmutableHashSet<T> will be O(log n))

I do not think there is any way to generate errors at compile time without some extension to the compiler. It might be easier to write a unit test. I.e. Make all your collections as static-readonly properties in a class, and use reflection to inspect the properties for uniqueness.

"would be nice if I would be aware of Unique problem at the compile time" - Maybe with an analyzer?

An IReadOnlySet<T> (backed by a HashSet<T>), a FrozenSet<T>, or an ImmutableSet<T> would all be better than your list. They'll remove duplicate elements at runtime (although not at compile-time), and the cost of doing the Contains check would be a lot less.

A perhaps better approach would be to add some attributes to your enum members. You can do this by using a class with static members instead of an enum, for example:
public class RetirementType
{
    public bool IsRetirementIra { get; init; }
    
    public static FrozenSet<RetirementType> RetirementIraTypes { get; }
    
    static RetirementType()
    {
        var retirementIraTypes = new List<RetirementType>();
        
        RetirementType Add(RetirementType retirementType)
        {
            if (retirementType.IsRetirementIra)
            {
                retirementIraTypes.Add(retirementType);
            }
            return retirementType;
        }
        
        k401 = Add(new());
        SEPIRA = Add(new() { IsRetirementIra = true });
        // ...
        
        RetirementIraTypes = retirementIraTypes.ToFrozenSet();
    }
    
    private RetirementType() { }
    
    public static RetirementType k401 { get; }
    public static RetirementType SEPIRA { get; }
    // ...
}

Then each RetirementType knows whether it's an IRA retirement type etc (this knowledge is contained in one place, rather than scattered around the code). To make life easier, we also construct the set of retirement IRA types in the static constructor, so it can be accessed from anywhere. This removes the problem detecting duplicate members at compile-time, since that's now something which you can't do anyway.
You would now do RetirementType.RetirementIraTypes.Contains(...).

I will mark your answer as a valid solution, because is a smart approach, but not quite applicable to my project because is an old one and these types are spread all over it and requires a serious effort to refactor, but I will use ImmutableHashSet for now. Thank you.

@DA Cool. Note that a FrozenSet<T> or a HashSet<T> (hidden behind IReadOnlySet<T>) will have much better performance unless you need to have immutable behaviour. The immutable collections let you easily add and remove elements while still keeping the original, unmodified collection: if you don't need that, you'll get better performance with the other set types.
